# Calculated height in vertical layout stops rendering margin values from elements inside

Tags: java, vaadin

I've got a Vertical Layout which I add 10 elements, that are wrapped in a CSS Layout, to.
All of these elements do have a fixed height of 60 pixels and 4 pixels margin. However: Since the Vertical Layout has a height of 100% each element is being wrapped in a `height: 10%` div.

Do you know how to prevent this dynamically calculation from happening? If I disable the `height: 10%` on the element, everything looks fine and works as it is supposed to be. Is the only solution a custom CSS Layout?

Best,
Felix

Comment: Why do you set the height to 100% in the first place? When you add 10 elements, it must somehow fill 100% height..

Comment: @AndréSchild Works! Don't know why I didn't think of the most simple way. Thanks!